# PHP/MYSQL - IF entra, pero ELSE no

Tags: php, html, mysql

pues aquí dándome de piñas porque mi código no funciona, a ver si pueden darme luz...

tengo mi formulario con folio y piezas a asignar, la cosa es que quiero que inserte cuando tengo disponible y que mande el echo cuando no tenga disponible, pero la cosa es que siempre inserta y claro, en mi tabla me da numero negativo, aquí el código:

```
if(isset($_POST["lista1"])) {
        $folio = $_POST["lista1"];
        $piezas = $_POST["txtPiezaAsig"];
        $q = "SELECT existencias_totales FROM productos_disponible WHERE folioProducto = '$folio'";
        //$existencias = mysqli_query($conexion, $q);
        $existencias = $conexion->query($q);
        $disponible = $existencias->fetch_assoc();
        if($piezas <= $disponible) {
            $query="INSERT INTO asignar_productos (id, usuario, folioProducto, nombre, asignado_a, obra_asignada, piezas_asignadas, unidad, fecha) VALUES ('NULL', '$usuario', '$lista1', '$lista2', '$txtAsig', '$txtObra', '$txtPiezaAsig', '$unidad', NOW())";
            //$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
            $consulta = $conexion->query($query);
            header("location: consultar-asignar-productos.php");
        }if($piezas > $disponible){
            echo "<div align='center'><font face='calibri' size='3'><b>La cantidad es superior al disponible</b></font></div>";
            header("refresh:1.5; url=asignar-productos.php");
        }
    }
```

Slds!!!

Comment: Intenta asi: `if($piezas <= $disponible['existencias_totales']) {`

Comment: En dónde está el `else`?

Comment: perdón, no lo edite, es ELSEIF, de todas formas tampoco entra el 2o IF @Bicho

Comment: en caliente! @alanfcm !!! ;D

Comment: @miiwtwo, como te comentaron previamente, el problema esta en la variable `$disponible`, la cual es un arreglo, por lo que el uso correcto seria `$disponible['existencias_totales']` en ambas condiciones de los `if`

Comment: gracias a ambos, tengo otro problema, pero lo formulare por separado ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$existencias->fetch_assoc();` devolveria un array asociativo por lo que estarias comparando un array con un integro.
Puedes usar `var_dump($disponible);exit;` para comprobarlo.

Puesto que `$piezas <= $disponible` siempre va a ser lo contrario a `$piezas > $disponible`no necesitas poner elseif(). Con poner else llega.

```
if($piezas <= $disponible) {
   //insert
}else{
   //mensaje de error.
}
```

Ademas, deberias sanitizar los valores que envie el usuario con [intval](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php) para asegurarte de que son numeros integros:

```
$folio=intval($_POST["lista1"]);
$piezas=intval($_POST["txtPiezaAsig"]);
```

Y tras [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) deberias poner exit si no quieres que se siga ejecutando.

```
<?php
//insert
header('Location: x');
exit;
```

Comment: gracias carlos, lo pongo en practica :)